# How to train gensim word2vec and check if the training was succesful?

Tags: python, word2vec, word-embedding

I want to train a word2vec model with gensim package. There are several approaches online how to train the model. In my case I have 500 finance reports as pdf-file with about 300 pages per file in german language.

Currently, my codes looks like this:

```py
w2v_model = Word2Vec(sentences=list_pre_word2vec,
                      min_count=20,
                     window=2,
                     vector_size=100,
                     sample=6e-5,
                     alpha=0.03,
                     min_alpha=0.0007,
                     negative=20,
                     workers=cores-1)

w2v_model.build_vocab(list_pre_word2vec, progress_per=10000)
w2v_model.train(list_pre_word2vec, total_examples=w2v_model.corpus_count, epochs=30, report_delay=1)
```

This code create some questions:

1. Is that the right approach? I don't understand in depth what is going on in this code and I'm a bit unconfident if it is works. Maybe you can explain what's going.
2. How do I know if the training was successful? Are there some attributes, metrics or something else to confirm it?

Answer (score 0):

Ultimately the test is whether the results make sense, both in general with some basic probes of sane results, and then for whatever your end-purpose is

A basic ad-hoc sanity check is to check whether the results of `w2v_model.wv.most_similar(probe_word)` make sense, as words similar in meaning/use. (You can check this with both general words, and those that you think specific to your corpus.)

If the results are nonsense, something went wrong. If results under certain parameters seem noticeably better than others, that's also a clue to good parameters for your corpus/purposes.

Once you've got a baseline working, the real test should be that the word-vectors are good for whatever your own specific downstream task happens to be. For example, if you're feeding them into a classifier, you can test different sets of word-vectors, from different preparations of the training corpus or parameter choices, against each other for what does best on you own specific, repeatable, quantitative evaluations.

As long as your `list_pre_word2vec` is data in the proper format – a Python re-ietarable sequence, where each item is a list-of-words, and no item has more than 10000 words – you're at least close enough that you should run things & see the results.

Enabling logging to at least the INFO level shows more info about progress, which over time you'll learn to understand – and may notice if some step reports an nonsensical tally, or duration.

I will say the parameters you've chosen are weird and arbitrary, suggesting you may be modeling your code after some substandard online tutorials/examples.

There's nothing magically-right or presumptively-optimal about the typical defaults, but they're not too bad, so changing them before you've even tried them puts you further from the bulk of prior experience.

So why use `min_count=20` instead of the default `min_count=5` unless you're sure you need to shrink the model by discarding mroe rare words?

Why use `window=2` instead of the default `window=5` which is far more common?

Why use `sample=6e-5` – far more aggressive than the default, probably more appropriate if you've got some humongous corpus?

Why use `alpha=0.03`, instead of the very similar usual default of `0.025`?

Why use `min_alpha=0.007` instead of the perfectly-fine default?

Why use 'negative=20' instead of the more-common default of `negative=5'?

Are you sure you need `epochs=30` instead of the default `epochs=5`, which will complete 6x faster and may be enough for a sizable corpus.

Are you sure `workers=cores-1` is appropriate on your system? (That's a fair heuristic up to about 8 cores, but with 16+, it will slow things when using a plain Python iterable as your corpus due to excessive thread contention.)

For all of these, there *might* be good reasons for tweaking the defaults - but you should know why, from specific experiments or well-explained precedents.

Keep things simple at first, and while you're learning, then vary them when you can test whether your changes are helping or hurting.